# GL11.glDrawElements does not work

Tags: opengl, lwjgl

First, i'm using LWJGL 3 and OpenGL 3.2

I'm trying to use the "indices" with the function GL11.glDrawElements but nothing rendered in the window.

Buffers generation code ( do not really useindices but I think it can still work) :

```
public void updateBuffers(Game game, int positionsAttrib, int texCoordsAttrib) { // positionsAttrib and texCoordsAttrib are pointer to shader program attribs

    FloatBuffer positionsBuffer = null;
    FloatBuffer texCoordsBuffer = null;

    IntBuffer indicesBuffer = null;

    try {

        this.vertexCount = this.tiles.size() * 4;

        positionsBuffer = MemoryUtil.memAllocFloat( this.tiles.size() * 3 * 4 );
        texCoordsBuffer = MemoryUtil.memAllocFloat( this.tiles.size() * 2 * 4 );
        indicesBuffer = MemoryUtil.memAllocInt( this.vertexCount );

        int i = 0;

        for ( Entry<TilePosition, Tile> tilesEntry : this.tiles.entrySet() ) {

            TilePosition tilePosition = tilesEntry.getKey();
            Tile tile = tilesEntry.getValue();
            String tileTextureIdentifier = tile.getTextureIdentifier();
            TextureDefinition tileTextureDefinition = game.getTexturesManager().getTextureDefinition("tiles");
            Rectangle tileTextureRectangle = tileTextureDefinition.getTilePosition( tileTextureIdentifier );

            if ( tileTextureRectangle == null ) continue;

            positionsBuffer.put( tilePosition.getX() ).put( tilePosition.getY() + 1 ).put( 0 );
            positionsBuffer.put( tilePosition.getX() + 1 ).put( tilePosition.getY() + 1 ).put( 0 );
            positionsBuffer.put( tilePosition.getX() + 1 ).put( tilePosition.getY() ).put( 0 );
            positionsBuffer.put( tilePosition.getX() ).put( tilePosition.getY() ).put( 0 );

            texCoordsBuffer.put( tileTextureRectangle.x ).put( tileTextureRectangle.y );
            texCoordsBuffer.put( tileTextureRectangle.x + tileTextureRectangle.width ).put( tileTextureRectangle.y );
            texCoordsBuffer.put( tileTextureRectangle.x + tileTextureRectangle.width ).put( tileTextureRectangle.y + tileTextureRectangle.height );
            texCoordsBuffer.put( tileTextureRectangle.x ).put( tileTextureRectangle.y + tileTextureRectangle.height );

            indicesBuffer.put( i ).put( i + 1 ).put( i + 2 ).put( i + 3 );

            i += 4;

        }

        positionsBuffer.flip();
        texCoordsBuffer.flip();
        indicesBuffer.flip();

        this.vao.bind(); // vbo and vao are class VertexBufferObject and VertexArrayObject which save internal id of buffers and most usefull functions

        this.positionsVbo.bind( GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER );
        VertexBufferObject.uploadData( GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, positionsBuffer, GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW );
        ShaderProgram.pointVertexAttribute( positionsAttrib, 3, 0, 0 );

        this.texCoordsVbo.bind( GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER );
        VertexBufferObject.uploadData( GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, texCoordsBuffer, GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW );
        ShaderProgram.pointVertexAttribute( texCoordsAttrib, 2, 0, 0 );

        this.indicesVbo.bind( GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER );
        VertexBufferObject.uploadData( GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indicesBuffer, GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW );

        VertexArrayObject.unbind();

    } finally {

        if ( positionsBuffer != null ) MemoryUtil.memFree( positionsBuffer );
        if ( texCoordsBuffer != null ) MemoryUtil.memFree( texCoordsBuffer );
        if ( indicesBuffer != null ) MemoryUtil.memFree( indicesBuffer );

    }

}
```

Used shader program :

```
// scene.vs :

#version 330 // edit : I have to change this line because of OpenGL used version

layout (location=0) in vec3 position;
layout (location=1) in vec2 texCoord;

out vec2 outTexCoord;

uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 model;

void main() {

    mat4 mvp = projection * view * model;
    gl_Position = mvp * vec4( position, 1.0 );

    outTexCoord = texCoord;

}

// scene.fs :

#version 330

in vec2 outTexCoord;

out vec4 fragColor;

uniform sampler2D textureSampler;

void main() {

    vec3 vertexColor = vec3( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 );

    vec4 textureColor = texture( textureSampler, outTexCoord );
    fragColor = vec4( vertexColor, 1.0 ) * textureColor;

}
```

And the rendering functions :

```
private void beginRender(Game game, int positionsAttrib, int texCoordsAttrib) {

    Texture texture = game.getTexturesManager().getTextureDefinition("tiles").getTexture();
    GL13.glActiveTexture( GL13.GL_TEXTURE0 );
    texture.bind();

    this.vao.bind();

    ShaderProgram.enableVertexAttribute( positionsAttrib );
    ShaderProgram.enableVertexAttribute( texCoordsAttrib );

}

private void endRender(Game game, int positionsAttrib, int texCoordsAttrib) {

    ShaderProgram.disableVertexAttribute( positionsAttrib );
    ShaderProgram.disableVertexAttribute( texCoordsAttrib );

    VertexArrayObject.unbind();

    Texture.unbind();

}

// render is called by render loop between clear and swapbuffer GL functions
public void render(Game game, int positionsAttrib, int texCoordsAttrib) {

    this.beginRender( game, positionsAttrib, texCoordsAttrib );

    GL11.glDrawElements( GL11.GL_QUADS, this.vertexCount, GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0 );

    this.endRender( game, positionsAttrib, texCoordsAttrib );

}
```

I'm not sure it's very clear, especially with my approximate English ..

Comment: If you are using OpenGL 4.5, then why is your shader version 330? Also: Are you using a core profile? In this case GL_QUADS are deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't  expicitely state it, but it looks like you're using a core profile (as you should). However, if so, `GL_QUADS` will be not available, and your draw call will just result in a `GL_INVALID_ENUM` error.

As a side note: since you say you use OpenGL 4.5, I'd strongly recommend that you use OpenGL's [debug output](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Debug_Output) feature during development, it will make spotting and interpreting any GL errors much easier, and might furthermore provide useful performance hints.

Comment: Thank you for your very fast answers ! I misspoke, in fact I force client to use version 3.2 at least, version 4.5 that I shared is actually the version installed on my computer. But thanks anyway for warning me that the constant GL_QUADS is depreacated.

Comment: Well, the 4.5 comment was only related to the debug output (which was incorporated into GL 4.3). It is still not clear to me if you're using a core profile or not (profiles were introduced in GL 3.2). In any case, checking for errors with `glGetError` could help, although it is not as nice as using debug output.

Comment: I managed to use GL43 debugging. Used window hints (What should I add to this?) :
`GLFW.glfwWindowHint( GLFW.GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW.GLFW_TRUE ); GLFW.glfwWindowHint( GLFW.GLFW_VISIBLE, GLFW.GLFW_FALSE ); GLFW.glfwWindowHint( GLFW.GLFW_VERSION_MAJOR, 3 ); GLFW.glfwWindowHint( GLFW.GLFW_VERSION_MINOR, 2 );`

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is now?

Comment: My question is how to use the "core profile" :) I don't really understand "profiles"

Comment: Well, if you're not already use the core profile,  using `GL_QUADS` won't be an issue, and my answer is not going to help much. As for how to create a core profile with GLFW: read the [documentation](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/window_guide.html#window_hints_ctx).

Comment: I just found a very bad problem, I put `GLFW.glfwWindowHint (GLFW.GLFW_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);` but in fact, the constant was not good, it should normally be GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR and also for the minor version. So I managed to put the "core profile". But for GL_QUADS, no alert.